# Preserve constness on assigning an object

Tags: c++

Is it possible to preserve constness of an object when assigning? Consider a class holding pointer to dynamic memory, a soft copy is expected on assignment. (There is some more complex logic including reference counting, but it is not relevant for the question).

```
class Vec {
private:
    int *data_; // dynamic array
public:
    int * Data() { return data_;} // access for modification
    const int * Data() const { return data_;} // read only access
    Vec subVec(int pos) { // create writable submat
        Vec ret; 
        ret.data_ = &data_[pos];
        return ret;
    }
    const Vec subVec(int pos) const { // create read only submat
        Vec ret; 
        ret.data_ = &data_[pos];
        return ret;
    }
};
void processVec(const Vec & src) {
    src.Data()[0] = 1; // not allowed, since src const
    Vec subVec = src.subVec(2); // call const version of subVec and create
                                // a soft copy - wrapper for a part of array.
                                // Assignment creates a copy, which removes constness
    subVec.Data()[0] = 1; // allowed! Since subVec is a copy, but modifies 
                          // identical dynamic memory from the wrapped src!
}
```

I would like `subVec.Data()[0] = 1;` to fail, since it is supposed to remain const.

Comment: Then declare `subVec` as const or provide only a `const` version of `Data()`

Comment: Where is your copy constructor?

Comment: @Yakk: since I want a soft copy, I rely on default copy constructor

Comment: Note that returning `const Vec` is mostly useless (and disallow some optimization)...

Comment: @captain: but it would prohibit editing of the content of non-const instances of Vec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would mimic the `iterator` and `const_iterator` idiom by creating a different return type when working with const or non-const object. Here an example implementing just a different type for const call to `subVec`:

```
class Vec {
 // ...
public:
 // ...

    const int * Data() const { return data_;} // read only access
    Vec subVec(int pos) { // create writable submat
        Vec ret; 
        ret.data_ = &data_[pos];
        return ret;
    }

    class SubVec
    {
    private:
        const int* data_;
    public:
        SubVec(const int* data) : data_(data) {}
        const int * Data() const { return data_;} // read only access
    };

    const SubVec subVec(int pos) const { // create read only submat
        SubVec ret(&data_[pos]);        
        return ret;
    }    
};
```

This will generate [the error you want in the const case](http://ideone.com/fasYFA) and [will compile in the non const case](http://ideone.com/oCWesu). Using `auto` allows a easier code writing for your code user.

Comment: How would you implement a function which should process a Vec? `void processVec(const Vec & src)` and `void modifyVec(Vec & inOutVec)` ?

Comment: @dousin What do you want them to do?

Comment: let's say `int sumVec(const Vec & src)` computes a sum of all elements (not modifying src), and `void modifyVec(Vec & inOutVec)` should modify elements of the inOutVec (multiply by 2...)

Comment: @dousin I don't see how it is related to your question...  A simple iteration on Data()  should work in both case.  (if you also have a way to get the size of data)

Comment: `Vec v1; Vec::SubVec v2=v1.subVec(2); modifyVec(v1); modifyVec(v2);`

Comment: @dousin  Won't compile. As v1 is not const,  subVec returns a Vec.  But you can provide a constructor from Vec if you  wish as const_iterator can be built from iterator.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44657/discussion-between-dousin-and-johan)

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is, that you are defining a smart pointer to some object, but you confuse constness of the smart pointer (the analogue to `Foo* const bar;`) with constness of the object (the analogue to `const Foo* bar;`). What you need, is to separate the constness of the pointer from the constness of the object.

You can relatively easily do so by using two smart pointer classes instead of one: A base class, that implements the smart pointer for a `const` object, and a derived class that implements the smart pointer for a non-`const` object.

With that, you can always demote your smart pointers to the "const" base class, make copy free "const" copies, etc. You might even add a constructor to the derived, non-"const" smart pointer class that takes a smart pointer of the "const" base class to make a deep copy of the data.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, the elements which are either const or non-const are assigned at run-time, hence the type system (which is static) can not help you with that. You'd need to store some boolean flag with each element and perform a run-time check on assignment to see if it allowed or not.

Comment: hmm, this would suffer from performance penality, which will not be accepted